# PHP PDO authentication method unknown to the client dialog

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

So recently my work has implemented a PAM plugin for our mariadb v10.2 to authenticate users through our company's LDAP and now PDO (and mysqli) is no longer able to connect to the database. The error message is as follows:

```
Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [dialog]
```

I have been looking everywhere for a solution, but I have been unable to find anything for resolving unknown authentication dialog, only problems with mysql 8's new auth scheme.

This is a quick test version of what I am using to connect and used to work prior to the switch to PAM:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;port=1234;dbname=mydbname', 'myuser', 'myldappw', [
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => "path/to/ca",
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => "path/to/key",
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => "path/to/cert",
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
]);
```

Any ideas on how to fix/workaround this? Thanks.

I have tried this on PHP 7.0, 7.1 and 7.2. Oddly I CAN connect via the PHPstorm database interface and SQLyog.

Comment: Does it work before? See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75645

Comment: Which driver does PDO use libmysqlclient or mysqld?

Comment: So that snippet worked before we used PAM authentication. PDO uses mysqlnd. I didn't see that bug, but at least someone else is having this issue.

Comment: Try to rebuild PDO with libmysqlclient driver. https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/management/pam_plugin.html

Comment: I will try that at work tomorrow.